# AppCompatDialogFragment did not create a View

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got this error:

```
09-08 08:21:27.855 2756-2756/com.ia.grafp.maturapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-08 08:21:28.168 2756-2769/com.ia.grafp.maturapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3562(491KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 48% free, 593KB/1143KB, paused 5.446ms total 31.994ms
09-08 08:21:28.444 2756-2769/com.ia.grafp.maturapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.571ms
09-08 08:21:28.548 2756-2756/com.ia.grafp.maturapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-08 08:21:28.820 2756-2769/com.ia.grafp.maturapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.720ms
09-08 08:21:28.824 2756-2769/com.ia.grafp.maturapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3222(542KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 1284KB/1941KB, paused 6.716ms total 15.066ms
09-08 08:21:28.853 2756-2756/com.ia.grafp.maturapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-08 08:21:28.854 2756-2756/com.ia.grafp.maturapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ia.grafp.maturapp, PID: 2756
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ia.grafp.maturapp/com.ia.grafp.maturapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
at com.ia.grafp.maturapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment did not create a view.
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2319)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
at com.ia.grafp.maturapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.ia.grafp.maturapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements PictureFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener /*Journal 1.)*/ {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {                       //** Kommuniziert mit PictureFragment (Journal 1.) )
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()      //**
                    .add(R.id.container, new PictureFragment()) //** // Container konnte nicht erreicht werden (can not resolve container) (Journal 2.)
                    .commit();                                  //**
        }
    }
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Wheeee!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ia.grafp.maturapp.MainActivity"
    android:id = "@+id/container">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        />


    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_picture"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_gallery_item"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

PictureFragment.java

```
package com.ia.grafp.maturapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link PictureFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link PictureFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PictureFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    protected static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    protected static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    protected String mParam1;
    protected String mParam2;


    protected OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public PictureFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PictureFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PictureFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PictureFragment fragment = new PictureFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picture, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }*/

    public void onAttach(MainActivity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

fragment_picture.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ia.grafp.maturapp.PictureFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:background="#5a2424" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What fragment class are you trying to show?

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment"
```

Look at that last line. That is not your `PictureFragment`

You probably meant this instead

```
android:name="com.ia.grafp.maturapp.PictureFragment"
```

And I don't think you need `tools:layout` inside that Fragment block since you're loading your own Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of using `<fragment .../>` in you `activity_main.xml`. It won't be able to inflate. So you are getting error like:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.ia.grafp.maturapp/com.ia.grafp.maturapp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error
>   inflating class fragment

Please remove the `<fragment .../>` for the `activity_main.xml` layout file.

Paste this code in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope my answer will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: What if the Fragment is wanted?